# Extract all strings values from code

Tags: php, regex

everyone. I have a problem and I can't resolve it.

Pattern: `\'(.*?)\'`

Source string: `'abc', 'def', 'gh\'', 'ui'`

I need `[abc]`, `[def]`, `[gh\']`, `[ui]`

But I get `[abc]`, `[def]`, `[gh\]`, `[, ]` etc.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP Code: Using negative lookbehind**

```
$s = "'abc', 'def', 'ghf\\\\', 'jkl\'f'";
echo "$s\n";
if (preg_match_all("~'.*?(?<!(?:(?<!\\\\)\\\\))'~", $s, $arr))
   var_dump($arr[0]);
```

**OUTOUT:**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "'abc'"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "'def'"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "'ghf\\'"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "'jkl\'f'"
}
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/y80Gas

Comment: I get `'abc', 'def', 'gh\', 'ui'` where it looks like the single quote was missed.

Comment: @anubhava, thanks, maybe it is exactly what I needed. But can you convert this code in PHP style?

Comment: Doesn't work if you have a term in the list like `'a\'\'b\''`

Comment: Khm. I think this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @indapublic This regex will fail to match `'ghf\\'` (the last backslashes mean a single literal backslash) in `'abc', 'def', 'ghf\\', 'jkl\'f'`

Comment: @Jerry yeah, it is true.

Comment: Yes it can be fixed and I will edit it in few mins when I am near computer. However keep in mind regex will become a bit more complex. My suggestion is only go for complex solution when you really need it. Is existing answer is working for your cases?

Comment: @anubhava, yes, past solution worked successfully. Your present solution I will check later and inform to you. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those matches are possible.

But if you mean to ask whether it's possible to get what's inside the quotes, the easiest here would be to split by comma (through a CSV parser preferably) and trim any trailing spaces.

Otherwise, you could try something like:

```
\'((?:\\\'|[^\'])+)\'
```

Which will match either `\'` or a non-quote character, but will fail against stuff like `\\'`...

A longer, and slower regex you might use for this case is:

```
\'((?:(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\\'|[^\'])+)\'
```

In PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/\'((?:(?<!\\)\\\'|[^\'])+)\'/', $text, $match);
```

Or if you use double quotes:

```
preg_match_all("/'((?:(?<!\\\)\\\'|[^'])+)'/", $text, $match);
```

Not sure why there's an error with `(?<!\\)` (I really mean one literal backslash) when it should be working fine. It works if the pattern is changed to `(?<!\\\\)`.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/FAUgsp)

### EDIT: Found a simpler, better, faster regex:

```
preg_match_all("/'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)+)'/", $text, $match);
```

Comment: It is small part of big task, and I can't use split. Your pattern is very heavy for big source string, isn't it?

Comment: @indapublic That's a common feature of Regex: to be very slow on big source strings :) But yes, it's about 2~3 times slower than a simple `\'([^']+)\'` regex.

Comment: I tried your last solution and get this error: preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 29

Comment: @indapublic Seems to be some escaping issues I don't understand... Adding some more backslash did the trick though: [viper7 demo](http://viper-7.com/YtOpYs).

Comment: @indapublic If you're looking for performance, my regex is 4%-31% faster than anubhava's. [His](http://regex101.com/r/hE2xJ5) compared to [mine](http://regex101.com/r/yQ8rX2) (had to adjust the backslashes since there are no backslash substitution on this site). Click on the little red bug to view the number of steps until successful match.

Comment: anubhava's solution is worked good and now I usign her regex in my code. I tried your solution later and maybe I change my decision. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @indapublic Got one regex which is about 2x faster than the previous regex I used and working just as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    // string to extract data from 
    $string  = "'abc', 'def', 'gh\'', 'ui'";

    // make the string into an array with a comma as the delimiter 
    $strings = explode(",", $string);

    # OPTION 1: keep the '

        // or, if you want to keep that escaped single quote
        $replacee = ["'", " "];
        $strings  = str_replace($replacee, "", $strings);
        $strings  = str_replace("\\", "\'", $strings);


    # OPTION 2: remove the ' /// uncomment tripple slash

        // replace the single quotes, spaces, and the backslash 
        /// $replacee = ["'", "\\", " "];

        // do the replacement, the $replacee with an empty string
        /// $strings = str_replace($replacee, "", $strings);


    var_dump($strings);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead you should use [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
str_getcsv("'abc', 'def', 'gh\'', 'ui'", ",", "'");
```

Comment: Sorry, but no. Thanks

Comment: @indapublic but no what?  My suggestion works for the requirement specified in your question.  Where does it fail?

Comment: As I said, I need regexp

Comment: @indapublic Why? Is this homework? Why do you **need** regexp when functions and libraries for this already exist?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I have source code, and I need to extract all string variables from this code. str_getcsv is bad solution for this. You can try)